# tinymce custom button

Tags: shortcode, woocommerce-offtopic, tinymce

I'm building Storefront child theme. I'm trying to add woocommerce shortcodes plugin into the my theme.

Button added but can't load translation file.

[image: custom tinymce button]

[class-wc-shortcodes-admin.php file](http://pastebin.com/UVX90LSG)

[wc-shortcodes-editor-i18n.php](http://pastebin.com/UWcxEQcP)

Translation file load codes in class-wc-shortcodes.php

```
    /**
 * TinyMCE locales function.
 *
 * @param  array $locales TinyMCE locales.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function add_tinymce_locales( $locales ) {
    $locales['woocommerce_shortcodes'] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/woocommerce-shortcodes/wc-shortcodes-editor-i18n.php';

    return $locales;
}
```

Comment: It looks as though this is pretty specific to WooCommerce so you might find it hard to get a good answer here. Officially plugin questions are off topic [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to `get_stylesheet_directory()`, and it works.